# Run a command in GNU and BSD Makefile and store the result into a variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to execute a command in a Makefile, store the result to a variable and reuse the result later.

In BSD Makefile, I can use the != operator:

```
PASSWORD != openssl rand -base64 48
```

In GNU Makefile, I can use the shell function:

```
PASSWORD := $(shell openssl rand -base64 48)
```

Is there a way to write this in such a way this is compatible with the two make?

---

**Expected output**

In both case, result of the command is assigned to PASSWORD, so I can reuse the same PASSWORD value in the Makefile:

```
quux:
    @echo $(PASSWORD)
    @echo $(PASSWORD)
```

If I run `make quux`, this will output twice the *same* password.

For example:

```
$ gmake quux
Y0ZrQQqLF9JK98x9UiIwWwcCN2Cq1wNqzph3ShG1RK0NeqbxWn6p4XB5zgHvfnbY
Y0ZrQQqLF9JK98x9UiIwWwcCN2Cq1wNqzph3ShG1RK0NeqbxWn6p4XB5zgHvfnbY
```

This is different than to use the backtick operator. In such cases, compatible with the two make, it will run the command each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GNU make 4.0, the BSD operator `!=` has been added for compatibility.  For versions of GNU make prior to that, you're out of luck.  You'll have to use the "poor man's" method, which is a recursive make invocation.

Be very careful because the BSD operator and the GNU make `$(shell ...)` function have slightly different semantics.  In your specific situation you'll not notice any difference because the output from the shell command doesn't contain any variable references (no `$`).

Comment: Good news it's arrived in the newest GNU make.